# Use Shakespeare-text and external file

Tags: haskell, yesod, template-haskell, hamlet, shakespeare-text

How can I convert the below example to use an external file instead of the embedded lazy text quasi quotes?

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, OverloadedStrings #-}
import Text.Shakespeare.Text
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TLIO
import Data.Text (Text)
import Control.Monad (forM_)

data Item = Item
    { itemName :: Text
    , itemQty :: Int
    }

items :: [Item]
items =
    [ Item "apples" 5
    , Item "bananas" 10
    ]

main :: IO ()
main = forM_ items $ \item -> TLIO.putStrLn
    [lt|You have #{show $ itemQty item} #{itemName item}.|]
```

This is from the [yesod online book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates).

Comment: From the page you linked, it looks like Yesod uses [this Hamlet function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hamlet/1.1.1/doc/html/src/Text-Hamlet.html#hamletFileWithSettings) to load a template from a file. This looks straightforward, building off of it for your own use should be fairly simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `textFile` function, along the lines of `$(textFile "some-file")`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Q to some string type?

Comment: Same issue. I can get textFile to load the file, but GHC is not happy with the resulting Q Exp.

Comment: Using Data.Text.Internal.Builder.toLazyText and passing an empty ("" :: Text) to the Exp value created by textFile, I was able to obtain a lazy Text that I could use in my code.

See: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.0.1/docs/Data-Text-Internal-Builder.html

I would wary against relying on an internal module though. There must be a better solution or, if not, then maybe a small library should be created for this purpose. Felipe Lessa started something like this for emails.

Comment: I've had the same problem. Using `Builder`'s internal builder works, but variable scoping wasn't quite right. The best solution I found so far is to define
`fromFile :: QuasiQuoter` where
`fromFile = quoteFile lt`

and then use `[fromFile|my_file.txt|]`.